# Display all invalid email using custom validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've created a custom validation request to read multiple email address in a single input.

CustomRequest

```
public function __construct()
{
    \Validator::extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        $emailArr = explode("\r\n", $value);
        $emailArr = array_filter($emailArr, 'trim');
        foreach ($emailArr as $key => $email) {
            $data = [
                'email' => $email
            ];
            $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Sample input:

```
test
test.q
test@test.com
```

Since the above input is invalid it will display this error:

```
One of the emails must be a valid email address.
```

Currently the above code is working but what I want is it to display each of the invalid email.
E.g

```
test is an invalid email
test.q is an invalid email
```

How do I do that? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Store the invalid emails in a variable and return it as well? Or perhaps store it in a session and unset it when you display them?

Comment: fixed it. added this `if (arrayHasValue($invalidEmails)) {
                $errorMsg = implode(',', $invalidEmails);
                return redirect()->back()
                    ->withErrors( ['emails' => trans('validation.emails', ['attribute' => $errorMsg])] )
                    ->withInput();
            }`

Comment: @Dean can you show how you achieved this

Answer (score 1):

This is now my current code.

```
public function __construct(Factory $factory)
{
    \Session::forget('invalid_emails');
    $factory->extend("emails", function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        $emailArr = explode("\r\n", $value);
        $emailArr = array_filter($emailArr, 'trim');
        $invalidEmails = [];
        foreach ($emailArr as $key => $email) {
            $data = [
                'email' => $email
            ];
            $validator = \Validator::make($data, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $invalidEmails[] = $email;
            }
        }

        if (arrayHasValue($invalidEmails)) {
            $errorMsg = implode(',', $invalidEmails);
            \Session::put('invalid_emails', $errorMsg);
            return redirect()->route('invitation')
                ->withErrors( ['emails' => trans('validation.emails', ['attribute' => $errorMsg])] )
                ->withInput();
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

And then in your controller method you just need to check for the session key email_invalid before you put some logic, etc...

I know it's a bit messy and I'm open to suggestions :)